# Problem with loops and conditionals. Flagging a value invalid when it should be valid

Tags: r, function, loops, conditional-statements

I'm having some problems with a conditional statement in a function I am working on.
I need to evaluate if there are enough data in each trimester for each year and each monitoring station. The number of data for the first trimester changes if it's a leap year.

So I did a nested loop to subset per year, station and trimester and then count the number of days with valid data and evaluate if it was equal or greater than the ref value (i. e., valid trimester).

My problem is that the loop I did to solve this is flagging me as invalid some data that should be valid. I can't find the reason why so I think is either on how I did the loop or the conditionals.

The loop:

```
X_trim_v<-data.frame()
  for (i in unique(X_max18h$year)){
    for (j in unique(X_max18h$id_station)){
      for (k in unique(X_max18h$trim)){
        X_m18<-subset(X_max18h, year == i & id_station == j & trim == k)
        if (leap_year(i) == T & trim == 1 & length(X_m18$day) >= 67){
            X_trim_v_tmp<-data.frame(year=i,id_station=j,trim=k,n=length(X_m18$day), validez="valido")
            X_trim_v<-rbind(X_trim_v, X_trim_v_tmp)
        } else if (leap_year(i) == F & trim == 1 & length(X_m18$day) >= 68){
            X_trim_v_tmp<-data.frame(year=i, id_station=j, trim=k, n=length(X_m18$day), validez="valido")
            X_trim_v<-rbind(X_trim_v, X_trim_v_tmp)
        } else if (trim == 2 & length(X_m18$day) >= 68){
            X_trim_v_tmp<-data.frame(year=i, id_station=j, trim=k, n=length(X_m18$day), validez="valido")
            X_trim_v<-rbind(X_trim_v, X_trim_v_tmp)
        } else if (trim == 3 | trim == 4 & length(X_m18$day) >= 69){
            X_trim_v_tmp<-data.frame(year=i, id_station=j, trim=k, n=length(X_m18$day), validez="valido")
            X_trim_v<-rbind(X_trim_v, X_trim_v_tmp)
          } else{
            X_trim_v_tmp<-data.frame(year=i, id_station=j, trim=k, n=length(X_m18$day), validez="invalido")
            X_trim_v<-rbind(X_trim_v, X_trim_v_tmp)
          }}}}
```

The data that should be valid:

```
year id_station trim  n  validez

2017    TLA     1   68  invalido

2018    CAM     1   68  invalido

2018    NEZ     1   68  invalido

2017    TAH     2   68  invalido

2018    LLA     2   68  invalido
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As a direction for solving you problem, try to avoid for-loops, especially nested ones. It seems a bit redundant. Look into the `dplyr` package,. From your description, group_by(year, station , trimester ), a count and a mutate would already get you close.

Comment: for readability, please do not use ifelse. Rather use case_when instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you're running into here with the loop specifically is that you're referencing a subset vector with `unique()`, then later, you're attempting to access the same i, j, or k values set by the subset loop, but using them to access the original dataset.

Without seeing what the full data set looks like, you appear to have a mismatch in how you access the data. If you set the loop conditional to be `for (i in unique(X_max18h$year)){`, you need to keep that consistent with how you access the data later on in that for loop. `unique(X_max18h$trim)` only returns a vector of length "2", so you will only loop twice, with a k value of 1 then 2, respectively.

If you want to use a for loop, I would suggest looping through each row and checking conditions in each row to your embedded logic.

```
for (i in length(X_max18h$trim)) {
    X_m18<-X_max18h[i ,c("year","id_station","trim")] #picking out row i, with selected columns
    if (leap_year(X_m18$year) == T & X_m18$trim == 1 & length(X_m18$day) >= 67){
        X_trim_v_tmp<-data.frame(cbind(X_m18,n=length(X_m18$day)) validez="valido")
        X_trim_v<-rbind(X_trim_v, X_trim_v_tmp)
}
```

Make sure you are introducing `"X_trim_v = NULL"` at some point as well. The code will error out the way I've written it.

Last item... if anything in your if or else if statements is wrong or missing, your code will default to what your final else statement is saying to execute. I don't see a column called "day" in how you initialize `X_m18`, so part of your if logic may not be read in or considered at all. Because this is AND logic, that could be causing your crash.

Answer (score 0):

As @Annet suggested, I used dplyr and case_when to solve it. I leave the answer here for future references. I'll try to come later and make a better example for anyone who has the same problem.

```
 X_trim_v<-X_max18h %>%
group_by(year, id_station, trim) %>%
summarise(n=n()) %>%
mutate(validez=case_when((trim == 3 | trim == 4) & n >= 69 ~ "valido",
                         (trim == 1 | trim == 2) & n >= 68 ~ "valido",
                         leap_year(year)== T & trim ==1 & n >= 67 ~ "valido",
                         TRUE ~ "invalido"))
```